# How big can I drop safely on a mountain bike

Tags: full-suspension, shocks

I have an 80 mm front shock (fork) and the back shock says it's 3 inches. What size jumps can I do without ruining the bike or shocks?

Comment: It also depends on the strength of the shocks, how much you weigh, and how strong your legs are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on technique, rather than equipment; Trials riders regularly drop several feet on rigid bikes.

You should use your legs to absorb the shock of landing to reduce the work done by the suspension, just as you would when jumping down from a height without a bike.

Comment: However, manufacturers issue guidelines for the purpose of warranty. Here is an [example](http://www.bike-manual.com/brands/trek/om/welcome/choose_bike.htm)/

Comment: +1 but equipment also comes into play

Comment: My link seems to be dead now and I denounce my comment. Instead I fully endorse this answer - drop as high as you can safely drop. How would warranty lawyers know!? In recent months I have learned to drop to flat 1 meter on my road bike!